# Camshaft synchronizer

Tags: engine

While changing my camshaft synchronizer I was pulling it out  I noticed the oil pump rod came up with it I tried to grab it but it dropped back down in to the motor not sure where it fell to please can everyone please help me . I'm trying to figure out  what I can do , either I drop the oil pan or pull the intake not sure witch one will be better . What a bad day, help please.  IT IS A 1996 FORD EXPLORER XLT 5.0
..

Comment: What vehicle?  Can you fish it out with a telescoping magnet?

Comment: And if you think fishing is challenging .... :)

Comment: More than likely it fell into the oil pan, stating which specific engine you are working on would be helpful to us.

Comment: It's a 1996 Ford explorer 5.0 V8

Answer (score 1):

get a flashlight and look into the hole it might have fallen back into the pump ...if not then dropping the pan is the solution make sure you put the new lock washer on the pump rod so that it wont come out again in case you need to change it